# matplotlib widgets not working in Jupyterlab 2.1.2

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, matplotlib-widget

I am running Jupyterlab 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 19.10, since my upgrade to Jupyter lab 2.x the matplotlib widget is not working.
Every time I try to create a figure:

```
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

I get this in the output cell:

```
Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
```

I upgraded and installed the extension both in the extension manager and from command line:

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab
pip install --upgrade nodejs
jupyter labextension install jupyter-matplotlib
```

but without any luck.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.